# LocalDate in Spring form

Tags: spring, jsp

This is my Entity

```
 @Entity
 public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int id;


 private String name;

 private String mobNum;

 private String email;



 String gender;


  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
  LocalDate bdate;

public LocalDate getDate() {
    return bdate;
}

public void setDate(LocalDate bdate) {
    this.bdate = bdate;
}



public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}



public User() {

}


public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getMobNum() {
    return this.mobNum;
}

public void setMobNum(String mobNum) {
    this.mobNum = mobNum;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

and here is my Spring-Form

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="add_student_data.htm" method="POST" commandName="user">
     <table>



          <tr>
          <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
          <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
          <td><font color="red" /><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>



          <tr>
          <td><form:label path="bdate" >Date Of Birth</form:label></td>
          <td><form:input path="bdate"/></td>
          <td><font color="red" /><form:errors path="bdate" cssClass="bdate" /></td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
          <td><form:label path="gender" >Gender</form:label></td>
          <td><form:radiobutton path="gender" value="M" label="M" />
          <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="F" label="F" /></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="mobNum">Mob Num</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="mobNum"/></td>
            <td><font color="red" /><form:errors path="mobNum" ccssClass="error"/></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
                <td><font color="red" /><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" /></td>
                  </tr>
        </table>     
                <input type="submit" value="submit">

     </form:form>
   </body>
</html>
```

when i want to open this fom error is occured like

"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dateOfBirth' of bean class [com.domain.User]: Bean property 'dateOfBirth' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"

I am using joda.org.time.LocalDate in User entity.What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: The error message and the code you show isn't in line with each other. However you don't have a property `bdate` you have a property `date`. You have a `getDate` and `setDate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your getter/setter method name and variable name in JSP do not match, change the following methods from:

```
public LocalDate getDate() {
    return bdate;
}

public void setDate(LocalDate bdate) {
    this.bdate = bdate;
}
```

to

```
public LocalDate getBdate() {
    return bdate;
}

public void setBdate(LocalDate bdate) {
    this.bdate = bdate;
}
```